# Find the tangent line in non derivable points

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives

I was studying the function $f(x)=\frac{2(x+1)^2}{|6x^2+3x|}$ and I was trying to find the tangents line in non derivable points which in this case are $x=0$ and $x=\frac{-1}{2}$. Is it possible? How can I calculate the two tangents? (I have some ideas but I'm not sure, so I ask you). I would first calculate the limits of each points (the left and the right side) then see what type of tangent I would obtain. Help me please! Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: By definition, the derivative of a function in a point exists if and only if the function has a well-defined tangent line in that point.

Comment: gain intuition by plotting: [ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+2%28x%2B1%29%5E2%2F%7C6x2%2B3x%7C ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(0)$ is undefined, and $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = \infty$, so $f'(0)$ is undefined.  This is also the case for $f(-1/2)$:  $\lim_{x \to -1/2} f(x) = \infty$, so again, the derivative is undefined.

Comment: You have confirmed my previous idea, thanks!